# Whats is more efficent, creating components by MXML or by SCRIPT | FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

im trying to figure out what is better for run-time, creating components in MXML or by SCRIPT?.  I built an app that recieves data from a server without knowing how much data exactly.
In worst case scenerio , ill need 10 LABELS and 2 DATAGROUPS.But i usually need something like 3 LABELS and 1 datagroup.
 So what is better? creating all components in advance and than not include in layout the ones i dont need, or make some checks and then create only the components i need by script? .
I made some tests , but it wasnt really decisive, run-time was pretty much simillar.Im guessing it must be stated somewhere what is better. Does anyone have an answer for me?

Thanks ahead [=

Comment: Generally, ActionScript components are more efficient, but MXML is often easier to build out and maintain.  MXML is turned into ActionScript under the hood, so you can always use the 'keep' compiler argument to review.  For just displaying a handful of labels I wouldn't expect significant performance difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex components can be added to an application using MXML or ActionScript 3.0.
MXML is compiled to ActionScript 3.0.   MXML components are just a tag version of an AS3 class.
MXML need flex framework,and mxml project need long compile time.
so mxml is slow.

And this is gud article

http://blog.vivisectingmedia.com/2008/04/the-flex-code-behind-pattern/

Comment: Techincally, you can use MXML w/o the Flex Framework.  A bunch of people have done presentations on this. It isn't used in practical usage, but some UI frameworks, such as Reflex, make use of this.  Also, to say "MXML Projects need a long compile time" is a bit of misnomer. The compiler is not perfect, but I do not think MXML is only factor involved.

Comment: The question which is faster AS3 or MXML looks like the good old question : which is faster - C++ code or C++ Builder code ...